# Is it possible to have different type of activation functions in different layer in Opencv neural network?

Tags: opencv, neural-network, layer

I know there are three types of activation functions provided in OpenCV neural network and sigmoid function is the default. I would like ask is it possible to have sigmoid function as the activation function at hidden layer while having identity function at the output layer?

Comment: Very interesting idea. Can you explain please, why do you want to use different activation functions between different layers? Some mathematical or logical reasons?

Comment: I came here via google while looking for an answer to the same question (i.e. how to set different activation functions for different layers in opencv ml::mlp). sigmoid as hidden and linear for output is pretty standard for regression (even if input/output is normalised).

Answer (score 0):

I just look at page [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/neural_networks.html#cvann-mlp-trainparams): at the method create. Look at the create method description:

activateFunc – Parameter specifying the activation function for each neuron: one of CvANN_MLP::IDENTITY, CvANN_MLP::SIGMOID_SYM, and CvANN_MLP::GAUSSIAN.
I do nont see any way to set or modify activation function, so I assume that if it is not mentioned in documentation, you'll not be able to create such network with different activation functions. But nothing prevents you from downloading source code and modifying construrctor and learning algorithm for your purpose.